# How to find the no of Questions?

Tags: contest-math, education, puzzle

Liz and Mary compete in solving problems. Each of them is given the same list of 100 problems. For any problem, the first of them to solve it gets 4 points, while the second to solve it gets 1 point. Liz solved 60 problems, and Mary also solved 60 problems. Together, they got 312 points. How many problems were solved by both of them?

Comment: One can use "algebra." Let $x$ be the number solved by both. That accounts for $5x$ points. How many total points were earned from the $2(60-x)$ problems solved by only one person?

Comment: We do not know the total points earned by one person. How do we form two equations to solve the value of x?

Comment: I could not figure out how to solve this question. We know that each of them solved 60 problems out of the 100 problems, but we do not know how many problems both solved in common. I am not clear how to form algebraic equations based on the given info.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  It could be that for all the problems they both solved, Liz solved it first.  She would then score $240$ and Mary would score $72$

Comment: @user39531:  you only have one unknown, $x$, so you only need one equation.  André Nicolas suggested you write an equation that computes the total number of points scored from the number of problems solved and equate that to $312$

Comment: @RossMillikan: Certainly the number is not determined, I was wrong about that. I was thinking of the symmetry that gives us $5x+(4)(2)(60-x)$ and solves the problem.

Comment: @user39531 is your question answered? It looks as though it is ..if yes then accept The Answer by clicking on the tick-mark ..otherwise if you want more explainiation then please drop a comment or edit your question accordingly as it looks like Andre Nicolas has very well answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

We can use "algebra." Let $x$ be the number of problems solved by both. Each such problem contributes $4+1$ points to the combined score, for a total of $5x$.

In addition, $(60-x)+(60-x)$ problems were solved by one person alone. These contributed $(4)(2)(60-x)$ to the combined score. We are told that the combined score was $312$. It follows that
$$5x+8(60-x)=312.$$
Solve this linear equation for $x$.

Once upon a time, before the advent of "algebra," the problem might have been solved as follows.

Let us guess that $60$ of the problems were solved by both of them. Then the total score would be $300$, which is $12$ short of $312$. Let us guess now that $59$ of the problems were solved  by both of them. That would add  $4+4$ points to the total score, and subtract $5$, for a net gain of $3$. Similarly, each problem taken out of the pool of problems solved by both adds $3$ to the total score. We need to add $12$ points, so we need to take $12/3=4$ problems out of the pool of problems solved by both. So $56$ of the problems were solved by both.

Comment: Is (60−x) not the number of questions solved by only one person? I am not clear how you get (60−x) + (60−x) problems solved by one person. I dont get the logic. How do you the number 4? Can you please explain it in a different way, step by step. Thanks so much

Comment: Liz solved $60$ problems. Of these, $x$ were problems that Mary also solved. So the remaining $60-x$ problems Liz solved were problems that Mary did not solve. Similarly, Mary solved $60$ problems, and $60-x$ of these were problems Liz did not solve. So there were $(60-x)+(60-x)$ problems solved by only one person.

Comment: That makes sense now. So how do you get the factor 4?

Comment: Whoever solves a problem first gets $4$ points. So for each problem that Liz solved and Mary didn't, Liz gets $4$ points and Mary $0$, for a total of $4$. Similarly, we et a total of $4$ points earned for each problem Mary solves but Liz doesn't. So the total number of points earned from questions only one of them solved is $4((60-x)+(6-x))$.